# C++ Boost 1.72.0 - 'defer': is not a member of 'std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_context>'

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, shared-ptr

I'm trying to use Boost's ASIO library to do easy networking on Windows for my project, but whenever I include anything that has to do with `std::shared_ptr` and `boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor`, I get this error:

`'defer': is not a member of 'std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_context>'`

```
bool ChatterboxService::Service::open()
{
    context = std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_context>();

    try
    {
        acceptor = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor>(context, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port));
    }
    catch (boost::system::system_error error)
    {
        std::cerr << error.what() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I've tried deleting, re-extracting, and re-compiling the entire library, but that made no difference. I've been Googling this problem for a couple of hours now and no-one else has ever seemed to have this problem. Any help at all is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to construct acceptor from shared_ptr, you should dereference it.

```
try
{
    acceptor = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor>(*context, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port));
}
```

Comment: Ah okay, that explains it. I guess it makes sense it wouldn't show up on Google because it was a pointer issue, not a Boost issue. So you can just de-reference a `shared_ptr` as if it was a regular pointer?

Comment: Yes, you can dereference to get underlying object.